# ajax и 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, form

Впервые пробую создать отправку формы через AJAX и получаю 500 ошибку сервера. Знаю, что подобные темы уже есть и много, но полезного ничего не подчерпнул. 
Собственно вот код отправки и обработки.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#send-btn").click(
  function(){
   sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'submit-your-app', 'action_ajax_form.php');
   return false; 
  }
 );
});
params = $('.add_comment').serialize()
$.post('add_comment', {id_advert: <your id advert>, data: params});
 
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
         result = $.parseJSON(response);
         $('#result_form').html('Имя: '+result.name+'<br>Телефон: '+result.phone);
     },
     error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="submit-your-app" class="i-form" method="post" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Фамилия Имя" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="phone"  placeholder="Контактный телефон" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        <button id="send-btn" type="button" ><span>отправить</span></button>
        </form>
```

```html
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
    if (isset($_POST['formData'])) {$formData = $_POST['formData'];}
 
    $to = "one@gmail.com"; /*Укажите адрес, на который должно приходить письмо*/
    $sendfrom   = "two@gmail.com"; /*Укажите адрес, с которого будет приходить письмо, можно не настоящий, нужно для формирования заголовка письма*/
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $subject = "$formData";
    $message = "$formData<br> <b>Имя пославшего:</b> $name<br> <b>Телефон:</b> $phone";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo '<center> Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!</center>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<center><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!</b></center>';
    }
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Попробуйте еще раз";
}
?>
```

[image: Вот что выводит <code>print_r($_POST);</code>]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверьте url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php) - например скопировав в адресную строку браузера. Или посмотрите во вкладке Network /  Firefox куда идет запрос POST ajax

Comment: @sterx по прямой ссылке дает ту же ошибку. В консоли путь верный, ошибка та же.

Comment: ну тогда в обработчике сделайте print_r($_POST);
короче проверьте - доходят данные POST до обратботчика и в каком месте затык если доходят. Отладка называется

Comment: Читайте еррор-логи.

Comment: @sterx добавил что поучилось в вопрос (изображение)

Comment: @u_mulder файл логов пустой

Comment: Значит либо смотрите не туда, либо логирование не включено.

Comment: @u_mulder логирование вкл, файл тот (прикрепил скрины)

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['formData']` - это что? Уберите.

Строки

```
    dataType: "html", //формат данных
```

и

```
        result = $.parseJSON(response);
```

противоречат друг другу. Выберите что-нибудь одно.

Comment: убрал все, но ничего не поменялось